# How do I start AWS Codepipeline from client?

Tags: pipeline, aws-cdk

I had built an AWS CDK code pipeline that triggers build on every git commit, but I want to trigger the build throw client function can anyone please guide me on how can I trigger the start-pipeline function throw the client-side.

Comment: You need to include more detail here if possible. When you say "client-side", what do you mean exactly? Do you mean the AWS CLI? Do you mean through an application? If so, what language is it written in? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AWS CLI to start the pipeline manually, the same thing is possible via a API call.

From: [Start a pipeline manually](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-rerun-manually.html)

```
aws codepipeline start-pipeline-execution --name MyFirstPipeline
```

Alternatively you can add a review button within CodePipeline.

From: [Manage approval actions in CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/approvals.html)

> In AWS CodePipeline, you can add an approval action to a stage in a
> pipeline at the point where you want the pipeline execution to stop so
> that someone with the required AWS Identity and Access Management
> permissions can approve or reject the action.

Comment: I want to start it automatically when the client press some button

Comment: You can do the same thing using a API call in your application when your button gets pushed. Alternatively you can give the client access to the AWS Console and add a review button within the CodePipeline.